# Google Android - how to figure out if 3g and 2g is turned on

Tags: android, wireless, gprs

I'm developing a simple application for the Google Android to turn on and off the wifi or 3g or 2g.

I see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#isWifiEnabled()
that you can see if the wifi is enabled or disabled and also us
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#setWifiEnabled(boolean)
to turn on and off the wifi.

I'm wondering if it's possible to do the same for 3G and for 2G/GPRS?
I know it's possible because you can turn off 3G and left 2G on.

Comment: what method did you find to turn off 3G and leave 2G on?

Comment: In the Wireless you can select "Use only 2G networks to save power"

Answer (score 13):

### 2G/3G

To determine your network type use:

```
TelephonyManager.getNetworkType();
```

here's some example code:

```
bool is3G = (manager.getNetworkType() == TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS);
```

Docs for the class can be found at: [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html)

### On/Off

To check if your telephone radio is on or off use:

```
ServiceState.getState();
```

To set it use:

```
ServiceState.setState(STATE_POWER_OFF);
```

It's unclear whether the setState method exists on all devices and functions in all states. There is no documentation for this method. Documentation for the class can be found at: [ServiceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/ServiceState.html)

This issue might also be relevant: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1065

Answer (score 2):

You can also use ConnectivityManager. Something like that:

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager =(ConnectivityManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 
NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
```